# Trigger causing Transaction does not match connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, triggers, transactions

I have a trigger that insert/update a value in a table_B whenever a value in table_A is updated. In certain scenarios (using Entity Framework) this trigger is causing a error "Transaction does not match connection".

Does anyone has suggestions ?

Code of the trigger is this:

```
  CREATE TRIGGER dbo.SetLastUpdateOnTableB
  ON dbo.TableA 
  AFTER UPDATE
  AS
  BEGIN

   IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE personId = (SELECT TableA.Id From TableA INNER JOIN inserted ON TableA.Id = inserted.Id))) 
   BEGIN 
       INSERT INTO TableB(PersonId, LastUpdate) 
       VALUES((SELECT TableA.Id From TableA INNER JOIN inserted ON TableA.Id = inserted.Id), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
   END 
   ELSE 
   BEGIN 
       UPDATE TableB 
       SET LastUpdate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
       WHERE personId = (SELECT TableA.Id From TableA INNER JOIN inserted ON TableA.Id = inserted.Id)
   END
  END
  GO
```

Comment: Your trigger is broken. `inserted` can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows. You need to re-write your statements to cope with that (and the fact that, during one particular run, *some* of those rows may represent new entries and *some* of them may be existing entries, so far as `TableB` is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Damien is right, the trigger is wrong and causing the error. Here the corrected version:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER dbo.SetLastUpdateOnTableB
 ON dbo.TableA 
 AFTER UPDATE
 AS
 BEGIN

  IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE personId IN (SELECT TableA.Id From TableA INNER JOIN inserted ON TableA.Id = inserted.Id))) 
  BEGIN 
      INSERT INTO TableB(PersonId, LastUpdate) 
      SELECT TableA.Id, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP From TableA INNER JOIN inserted ON TableA.Id = inserted.Id 
  END 
  ELSE 
  BEGIN 
      UPDATE TableB 
      SET LastUpdate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
      WHERE personId IN (SELECT TableA.Id From TableA INNER JOIN inserted ON TableA.Id = inserted.Id)
  END
 END
 GO
```

Comment: This is still partially broken. Imagine an update to two rows in `TableA`. One of them doesn't currently have a row in `TableB`. The other one does. Your `IF` can only choose one action or the other, and neither action is correct for both rows. Remove the `IF`, just have both the `UPDATE` and the `INSERT` and control which rows from `inserted` are used for each statement using `WHERE` clauses.